# gcloud app deploy says: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: go, google-app-engine, gcloud

I am struggling to deploy a simple Go app to Google App Engine flexible environment. (This is a very cut-down version of a larger app.) When I run `gcloud app deploy --project=<projectID>` it terminates with an error, and has this in its output:

```
...
Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/go1-builder@sha256:68b86e4c97438df4c9e36c55ad724079b453398a0a44c29748fb5685eef73895
Step #0: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/go1-builder@sha256:68b86e4c97438df4c9e36c55ad724079b453398a0a44c29748fb5685eef73895
Step #0: go: github.com/go-stack/stack@v1.8.0: git init --bare in /workspace/_gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/6963ea18be763686e7a9697733dd92bfcc0d45b687afce82da04992523d91cd1: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
Step #0: go: github.com/inconshreveable/log15@v0.0.0-20200109203555-b30bc20e4fd1: git init --bare in /workspace/_gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/fe2a07d0f4107d9daa39043733e909094a5b926cca44d0f7269e7a2185dbef15: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
Step #0: go: github.com/mattn/go-colorable@v0.1.6: git init --bare in /workspace/_gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/f7e99db597f4d2fe3e4509a9af308dace72a13292b505deb909cd0df29c1468a: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
Step #0: go: error loading module requirements
Finished Step #0
```

It does work if I delete `go.mod`, but (I think) I need `go.mod` to compile and test it locally. It does work if I don't import the external package, but of course I need external packages in my larger app. It does work if I choose the standard environment, but I need the flexible environment for my larger app.

How can I deploy this app successfully to a flexible environment?

My local Go is 1.13, and I have the latest version (292.0.0) of gcloud. Apart from `go.sum`, the contents of my directory is...

app.yaml:

```
runtime: go1.12
env: flex
```

go.mod:

```
module mymodulename

go 1.13

require (
        github.com/go-stack/stack v1.8.0 // indirect
        github.com/inconshreveable/log15 v0.0.0-20200109203555-b30bc20e4fd1
        github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.6 // indirect
)
```

main.go:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        "os"

        "github.com/inconshreveable/log15"
)

func main() {
        log := log15.New()

        http.HandleFunc("/", helloHandler)

        port := os.Getenv("PORT")
        if port == "" {
                port = "8080"
                log.Info("Using default port", "port", port)
        }

        log.Info("Listening", "port", port)
        if err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil); err != nil {
                log.Crit("ListenAndServe", "error", err)
                os.Exit(1)
        }
}

func helloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, there")
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Clearly described question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC Flexible *doesn't* support modules (Standard does, go figure!).

You can:

- either use a custom runtime;
- or, delete the `go.mod`|`go.sum` and try again.

I copied your `app.yaml` and `main.go` and it worked for me.

One change to your `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: go
env: flex
```

Then:

```sh
go get github.com/inconshreveable/log15
go run main.go
INFO[05-15|09:33:26] Using default port                       port=8080
INFO[05-15|09:33:26] Listening                                port=8080
```

and:

```sh
curl --silent http://localhost:8080
Hello, there
```

and:

```sh
gcloud app deploy --project=${PROJECT}
curl --silent $(\
  gcloud app describe \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(defaultHostname)")
Hello, there
```

Comment: Argh! That is *not* clear from the documentation, although (now that you've said it) I've found a reference that merely implies it. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/runtime Thank you. Also, I've found I can exclude go.mod in .gcloudignore, and that also works.

Comment: It's not clear. I was surprised by this too! Standard may be a better choice ceteris paribus. Standard supports 1.12 and has beta support for 1.13. Since Flex is containerizing the app for you, why not just go custom? Then you get to choose to use Cloud Run too.

Comment: "...why not just go custom?" Because I want to limit the number of technologies I need to learn and maintain. But eventually that might be a good route.

Comment: Fair! Flexible builds the container for you. ToMH `gcloud container images list --project=${PROJECT}` would enumerate it. It's configured to default to `:8080`. Flexible sidecars it with Nginx when it deploys it but you could `gcloud run deploy ...` the container.